# Convert the temperature with change in other component with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which convert the weather and I want to use it for the forecast as well. I mean when the user clicked on °F, not only the current weather but also the forecast change to Fahrenheit. I'm learning React and was hoping to know how I can do this. thanks in advance.

```
 import React from "react";
import WeatherIcon from "./WeatherIcon";
export default function ForecastDay(props) {
  function showMax() {
    let max = Math.round(props.data.temperature.maximum);
    return max;
  }
  function showMin() {
    let min = Math.round(props.data.temperature.minimum);
    return min;
  }
  function showDay() {
    let date = new Date(props.data.time * 1000);
    let days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    let day = days[date.getDay()];
    return day;
  }

  return (
    <div className="waether-forcast">
      <div className="forecast-date">{showDay()}</div>

      <div>
        <WeatherIcon code={props.data.condition.icon} size={43} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>
          <span>{showMax()}</span>
        </strong>
        °<span> {showMin()}°</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is the other component that I want to get the data from
I put my github link but here is the code.
I did use this component in my forecast. tired to call it but it gives me °F and °C for each temp but I want with on click all of them change.
I read that I can make it like a global variable. not sure how to do that.
or should I instead use the useEffect and change the Url for the API from
"metric" to "imperial"?

```
export default function WeatherTempUnit(props) {
  const [unit, setUnit] = useState("celsius");
  function showFarn(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setUnit("fahrenheit");
  }
  function showCel(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setUnit("celsius");
  }
  function fahrenheit() {
    return Math.round((props.celsius * 9) / 5 + 32);
  }
  if (unit === "celsius") {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{props.celsius}</span>
        <span className="units">
          °C |{" "}
          <a href="/" onClick={showFarn}>
            °F
          </a>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{fahrenheit()}</span>
        <span className="units">
          <a href="/" onClick={showCel}>
            °C{" "}
          </a>
          | °F
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Github code](https://github.com/shahrzadblackfox/my-weather-app/tree/master/src)

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any sort of F/C conversion code.

Comment: @Andy Hello, I didn't want to make it long so I linked my github code. but I added the code for the converter component as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your web page contains a global switch between °C and °F, I suggest to give every "temperature element" two attributes: the temperature in °C and the unit. Which number the element displays depends on both these attributes. And all "temperature elements" should switch their unit simultaneously when the global switch is flipped.

Sorry for not knowing React, but here is a solution using [HTML custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements) that conveys this idea. I hope it can be translated to React (by another answerer?).

```js
class Temperature extends HTMLSpanElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["tempC", "unit"];
  }
  static instances = new Set();
  static setUnit(unit) {
    for (var i of Temperature.instances) i.setAttribute("unit", unit);
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    Temperature.instances.add(this);
  }
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (oldValue !== newValue) {
      if (this.getAttribute("unit") === "C")
        this.textContent = this.getAttribute("tempC") + "°C";
      else
        this.textContent = Math.round((this.getAttribute("tempC") * 9) / 5 + 32) + "°F";
    }
  }
}
customElements.define("my-temperature", Temperature, {
  extends: "span"
});
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  debugger;
  Temperature.setUnit(this.unit.value);
}, true);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="unit" value="C" checked/>°C
  <input type="radio" name="unit" value="F" />°F
</form>
<span is="my-temperature" unit="C" tempC="0"></span>
<span is="my-temperature" unit="C" tempC="37"></span>
<span is="my-temperature" unit="C" tempC="100"></span>
<span is="my-temperature" unit="C" tempC="-273"></span>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with HTML custom elements but I will study them. thank you.